# Opencv compare Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I tried to compare 2 black and white images with the function, opencv provides (compare()). At first i declare some variables and then i just try to compare the black and white images just like in the documentation of opencv. At the end i just calculate the confidence percentage. But every time i run m program i got this error:

```
OpenCV: terminate handler is called! The last OpenCV error is:
OpenCV(4.3.0) Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have
 the same size and the same type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array') in compare, file C:\OpenCV\opencv\sourc
es\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp, line 1228
```

Here is my code:

```
Mat img2 = cv::imread("...");
Mat result;
Capture >>img1;
cv::compare(img1, img2, result, cv::CMP_EQ);
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

But the error is pretty much verbose. Even the documentation (https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html, not really version from tag but it shouldn't be relevant) says that:
*Elements of two arrays when src1 and src2 have the same size:*

I believe you could resize the second image to match first image's size:
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20resize(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20Size%20dsize,%20double%20fx,%20double%20fy,%20int%20interpolation)
but not sure if such comparison would be okay for you.

You can check Mat's size as follows:

```
Mat img2 = cv::imread("...");
int rows = M.rows;
int cols = M.cols;
```

By the way, you tagged the question with OpenCV3.1, yet in the error message we can see 4.3.0. You sure you are using the correct version?